# Query Db2 - Correction of two tables without result

Tags: db2

These are two tables with the data entered:

`THERA.CLASS_HDR VALUES('BAT12', 'Regola Valore x calcolo qte', 20, null, null, null, 'N', null, null, 'N', 'N', 'N', 'PRIMROSE', null, null, 'com.thera.thermfw.plexweb.PlexDOList', 'com.thera.thermfw.plexweb.servlet.PlexGridActionAdapter', null, null, null, 'N', null, null, null, 'N', null, 'N', 0, 0, null, null, null, 'N', 'N', 'ADMIN_001', CURRENT TIMESTAMP, 'Y', 'N');`

`THERA.CLASS_HDR_NLS VALUES('BAT12', 'it', 'Regola Valore x calcolo qte', 'Regola Valore x calcolo qte');`

Table:

1. THERA.CLASS_HDR
2. THERA.CLASS_HDR_NLS

I made the query:

```
select * 
from THERA.CLASS_HDR
join THERA.CLASS_HDR_NLS 
ON THERA.CLASS_HDR.CLASS_NAME = THERA.CLASS_HDR_NLS.CLASS_NAME  
where CLASS_NAME = 'BAT12' AND  language='it'
```

Result:

> [SELECT - 0 modified lines] [IBM] [CLI Driver] [DB2 / NT64] SQL0203N A
>   reference to the "CLASS_NAME" column is ambiguous. SQLSTATE = 42702

where did I make the query wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It clearly states, that the reference to a column `CLASS_NAME` is ambiguous, which means that both these tables have this column, and you must specify explicitly, which one you want to use in the expression `CLASS_NAME = 'BAT12'`.
If you want to use this column from the `THERA.CLASS_HDR` table, it must be like this:

```
select * 
from THERA.CLASS_HDR 
join THERA.CLASS_HDR_NLS 
ON THERA.CLASS_HDR.CLASS_NAME = THERA.CLASS_HDR_NLS.CLASS_NAME  
where THERA.CLASS_HDR.CLASS_NAME = 'BAT12' AND language='it'
```